# How can I import a png with different opacity layers in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, blend-modes

I'm a beginner in illustrator and I would like to import this fog .png file in Illustrator and overlay it onto this repetition of X. The problem is that in the faded areas with different opacities the Xs become white. How can I solve this issue? I'll share also what I'm trying to recreate. I even tried with different blend modes but I couldn't solve it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You uploaded jpgs, thereby discarding any transparency layer, meaning we cannot see what you mean.

Comment: What is this 2nd image? is it from Photoshop or Illustrator? I can see the problem you mentioned in 1st image, but what about 2nd image?

Comment: For Tetsujin, probably I didn't explain it correctly: basically the smoke png has some areas where it is semitransparent, but when I import it in Illustrator, that semitransparent areas make the x pattern white. For Vikas, as I said the second picture is the graphic I'm trying to recreate and that one was made in photoshop

Comment: Also, if you're asking why am I importing this png into illustrator: I'm having troubles to recreate that smoke and I can't find a good tutorial, so considering that the png is high quality enough to not lose quality when printed I decided to keep it as a raster instead of spending lots of time trying to vectorize it

Comment: @usr287001  - oops. yeah I meant Illustarator has limited raster capabilities. A case of thinking of the word, but the fingers wrote something else ;) - well noticed, I've deleted the comment and written again.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I have to say that editing PNG images in Illustrator is probably a really bad idea. Illustrator has extremely limited raster capabilities. You'd probably be better doing it in a raster image editor such as Photohsop. Also it's not clear what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: png can not have layers.

Comment: "Xs become white" -- merely because Illustrator has a white work area by default. The *transparency is merely allowing the work area to show through*, that's all. Try View > Show Transparency Grid.

Answer (score 1):

You placed the triangles above the clouds but in the image you are trying to recreate the clouds layer is simply above the triangles.